# Backyard Planetary Escape: From the Earth to the Moon, the Jeb Kerman way

Tags: space-travel, spaceships, engineering, construction, rockets

A pair of aerospace engineers discovers that the New World Order wants to depopulate Earth by means of starting a nuclear war on the 1st of January of [Enter number between 2025 and 2040]. The elite themselves is planning to wait out the war in sleep pods and hibernate for 3.000 years. During that time, Earth will be uninhabitable for humans and most animal species. For a variety of reasons, the family is unable to reach a bunker or sleep in the pods themselves (because the pods only work for Reptilians).

As nobody believes their "crazy conspiracy theory", they must now find a way for them and their families (both have a wife and 2 children) to escape Earth and reach a secret Soviet or Nazi base located on the dark side of the Moon, **without the resources and support of NASA**.

The aerospace engineers live on a farm in a sparsely-populated region of the Midwestern United States. One of them has left NASA to become a private construction contractor and is not only a multi-millionaire but also has access to heavy-grade equipment.

The families (2 men, 2 women, 4 children in total) must all fit into the vessel they will build.

The mission should entail **successfully launching from the farm, reaching LEO, transferring to the Moon, deorbiting and safely landing near the base in question**. Precise calculations could theoretically allow for a "Direct Ascent" approach without the orbital phases, as long as it saves fuel.

Of course, the standards are not as high as for official NASA missions. The families should have a **reasonable** chance of survival, as the alternative would be certain death on Earth.

The project has to be veiled in secrecy, to prevent others from trying to board the rocket on Launch Day. Workers from the second engineer's company and foreign contractors may be used, but they should not be able to understand what they are working on in reality.

Materials that are not available in a normal Midwestern industrial/construction environment can be sourced through a military contact or stolen, in reasonable extents. An airport and an airplane cemetery are located nearby, and the families are potentially able to make a trip to the coast to retrieve a small submarine graded for work at a depth of 2.000 meters.

**Design this mission and the necessary construction and preparatory processes.**

Take into account that any information leaks will result in secret agents trying to actively track down and kill the families.

**The preparation time is five years.**

Comment: (1) There is no question mark in this question. (2) How is this different from what Elon Musk is doing in real life at [Boca Chica](https://arstechnica.com/science/2020/08/today-may-be-the-day-spacexs-starship-prototype-takes-flight/)? (Look at the gorgeous pictures in the article, showing how a private company is building a stainless steel spaceship in a field in Texas using ordinary rented construction equipment.)

Comment: It's real hard to hide the Saturn-V/Energia/SLS-class rocket that you will need to transport 8 passengers. "Hi, this is the FBI. We noticed that you delivered about 600,000 lbs of RP-1 rocket fuel over the past couple months to a farm in the midwest. Would you mind telling us the *exact* location of delivery? Thanks. "

Comment: Yeah, this sounds basically like a sequel to the movie *The Astronaut Farmer*.  Watch that film and expand on it.

Comment: Sounds like a job for legos

Answer (score 5):

first problem- people will notice a several story tall steel tube on your property

second problem- people will notice when you start buying things to make a rocket

third problem- even IF you make a rocket and IF nobody finds out about it and IF you launch right and IF you make it to the moon, they should've been making rockets in the first place.

fourth problem- you can't just google rocket instructions(i think), and even if these guys are engineers, there''s no guarantee the rocket will work. Like Erik Hall said, it'll probably blow up a few times.

fifth problem- If you make it to space, what's to stop your evil people from launching a rocket at your rocket? ICBMs already go into space, so all they have to do is line it up with the rocket and send it on it's way after modifying the targeting system. They don't even need a payload!

sixth problem- your builder people have to make a rocket while also working their jobs, which will take a lot of time, and if they get fired halfway through they won't have any money to finish the project.

seventh problem- it would probably be cheaper and easier to build yourself a bunker where you can live out the rest of your life and line it with lead if your really worried about radiation. bunkers don't burst into flames during test runs.

Comment: Zeroth problem: a nuclear war just won't do what the OP thinks.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually this is possible, after all, SpaceX is building Starship prototypes and test articles in Boca Chica Texas with the crews welding segments together under essentially large tents.

[image]

*Actual backyard spaceship engineering*

While Robert A Heinlein would approve, a closer examination of the picture demonstrates that no two engineers, no matter how talented, would be able to do this in any reasonable time frame. There is the launch pad, the fuelling area and tankage, roads and accessways to bring in the materials, cranes to hoist the segments into the air etc. A pretty large capital expense, and requiring hiring work crews to build all the various parts.

NOT shown in the picture are the steel mils which create the coils of steel, the SpaceX facility which manufactures the Raptor rocket engines, the places where all the sub components are manufactured and tested, the software engineers programming all the various computers, sensors and doing testing...There is a reason that the person behind all this is a guy named Elon Musk, and a large part of it is he is a billionaire with independent means.

We haven't even gotten around to dealing with the bureaucracy - who is filling out all the paperwork for building permits, doing the tax paperwork for all the employees or even just ensuring the invoices are being paid in a timely manner? Another set of employees or expert contractors will be needed to deal with that.

All this even ignores the premise - if alien lizard people are planning to sterilize the Earth in a nuclear Holocost, wouldn't they interfere with the plans? holding up permits or shipments of steel, or overlooking obvious flaws in the tank farm which could lead to an explosion are all steps which can easily be taken, especially if you *are* the government. EPA or health and safety inspectors can show up and tie your organization in knots, and a tax audit would stop you in your tracks.

And what other dirty tricks might they have up their sleeves? How about "mostly peaceful" protesters coming to your assembly area?

So building a rocket capable of flying to orbit is a pretty big deal, even with fairly simplified systems. Don't forget as well, even the Starship needs a heavy booster to get into orbit, and the Starship then needs fuelling in orbit to continue to the Moon, you need to build several tankers as well.

So while on the surface it seems possible to build a spacecraft in your back yard, there are simply so many jobs that need to be done and an entire industrial ecosystem to access to make it even remotely possible. So under your parameters, this is a non starter.

Comment: The cranes and other building equipment are rentals, from the usual companies which rent out construction equipment. The welders belong to a company which normally builds water tanks. (For real. It's what makes this spacecraft building facility so fascinating -- it really brings home the idea that we have truly entered the space age.) (And SpaceX is profitable -- it is building the Starship system with the money it earns by lifting satellites.)

Comment: Not disagreeing, but pointing out that the production is far beyond the capabilities of just two people and their families -no matter what Robert A Heinlein's ghost might think.